# Read strings from ReadableStream line-by-line

Tags: javascript, typescript, bun

I'm using Bun to communicate with a `stockfish` child process.

```js
let process = Bun.spawn(["stockfish"], { stdin: "pipe" });
```

The stockfish CLI reads commands from stdin and writes commands to stdout. Once the process is started, it stays alive, responding to commands without closing.

When calling `Bun.spawn` with these parameters, Bun returns an instance of `Subprocess<"pipe", "pipe", "inherit">`. This object has a `stdout` property which is an instance of `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>` for accessing the data.

Since `stockfish` always outputs a newline with each line it prints, I need to be able to read strings from the stream line-by-line. Ideally, I could do something like this.

```js
process.stdin.write(`isready\n`);
process.stdout.readLine(); // "readyok"
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?